# Rails: How can I access a model's "errors" from a separate controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a resource called "Rating" (which has the standard actions: `create`, `update`, `destroy`).  I have a form for this resource which is rendered in another controller (called `MoviesController`).

How can I access the `RatingsController`'s `@rating` from within the `MoviesController`?

The `RatingsController`:

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rating, only: [:update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
    @rating.rater = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.save
        format.html do
          redirect_to movie_path(id: @rating.rottentomatoes_id),
            notice: 'Rating was successfully created.'
        end
      else
        format.html { redirect_to movie_path(id: @rating.rottentomatoes_id) }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.update(rating_params)
        format.html do
          redirect_to movie_path(id: @rating.rottentomatoes_id),
            notice: 'Rating was successfully updated.'
        end
      else
        format.html { redirect_to movie_path(id: @rating.rottentomatoes_id) }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @rating.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to movie_path,
          notice: 'Rating was successfully destroyed.'
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_rating
    @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])
  end

  def rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:rottentomatoes_id, :rating)
  end
end
```

And the `MoviesController`:

```
require 'httparty'

class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    movie_url = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/'
    api_key    = ''

    url = movie_url + params[:id].to_s + ".json?apikey=#{api_key}"
    movie_response = HTTParty.get(url)
    @movie = JSON.parse(movie_response.body, symbolize_names: true)
    @rating ||= (
      Rating.find_by(rottentomatoes_id: params[:id], rater: current_user) ||
      Rating.new(rottentomatoes_id: params[:id], rater: current_user)
    )
  end

  def search
    search_url = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json'
    api_key    = ''

    if request.GET[:title]
      title = URI.encode(request.GET[:title])
      url = search_url + "?apikey=#{api_key}&q=#{title}&page_limit=10&page=1"
      rottentomatoes_response = HTTParty.get(url)
      response_dict = JSON.parse(rottentomatoes_response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      @movies = response_dict[:movies]
    else
      @movies = []
    end
  end
end
```

And the `MovieController`'s `show` form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @rating do |f| %>
    <% if @rating.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@rating.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this rating from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
                <% @rating.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.input :rottentomatoes_id, as: :hidden %>
    <%= f.input :rater_id, as: :hidden %>
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :rating,
          [
            [0, '0'],
            [1, '1'],
            [2, '2'],
            [3, '3'],
            [4, '4'],
            [5, '5'],
            [6, '6'],
            [7, '7'],
            [8, '8'],
            [9, '9'],
            [10, '10']
          ],
          :first,
          :last
    %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the errors back to the MovieController:

```
format.html { redirect_to movie_path(id: @rating.rottentomatoes_id, errors: @rating.errors) }
```

And then in the MovieController `show` method:

```
if(params[:errors])
    @errors = params[:errors]
end
```

Then replace `@rating.errors` with `@errors` in the Movie Show view.